# Nginx module: how to get variables value from conf file

Tags: nginx, module, reverse-proxy

I have Nginx server acting as a reverse proxy. From its downstream, the request sets a header info about the ssl protocol for Nginx to use for proxy. I put this info in a variable in the nginx.conf file called "$origin_ssl_protocol". 
So it looks like:

```
proxy_ssl_protocols  $origin_ssl_protocol;
```

Now the problem is how does the Nginx module (the function handler) get the value of this variable? As far as I know, the handler for proxy_ssl_protocols is "ngx_conf_set_bitmask_slot", and it only accepts the pure values like TLSv1, SSLv3, rather than a variable holding these values.

I want to develop my own module, does anyone know how Nginx get the value of a variable in the Conf file (assuming that variable already has a valid value)?

Comment: What's the reason you want that?

Comment: I want nginx to connect to the origin based on some dynamic settings, for example the customer requirements from the database. The downstream can fetch the data from the db, then make a request to nginx server,  forwarding this ssl protocol info in terms of the header.

Comment: I can't understand why you want nginx to connect to upstream using exactly the same protocol that used by client?

Comment: To make things more clear, what I need is the following:

Comment: To make things more clear, what I need is the following:  set $origin_sslprotocol_1 "TLSv1";       Set $origin_sslprotocol_2  "TLSv1.1";     Proxy_ssl_protocols_new_module $origin_sslprotocol_1 $origin_sslprotocol_2;   Since the original directive supports one or more args, I also need the new directive supports the same.

Comment: I just want to let the user to choose the particular protocol for nginx to connect to the origin server (and only the connection to origin, not from client to nginx). Let's say this user choice can be fetched from the database, and then stored in the variable $origin_ssl_protocol